# How to effectively make ascending sequences?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to make a program which involves ascending sequences. N is for the size of the sequence and K is the maximum number, for example

Input: `2,3`

Output: `6 (1,1 - 1,2 - 1,3 - 2,2 - 2,3 - 3,3)`

My current code doesn't output 6 but 3. I know this is probably not the way to find the amount of sequences. From what I see, something is wrong in the recursion. Can you please help me find the problem and fix it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
long long n,k,cnt=0;
long long seq(long long n, long long k, long long first){
   if(n==first){
       return cnt;
   }
   for(long long i=first;i<=k;i++){
        cnt = cnt + 1;
   }
   return seq(n,k,first+1);
}
int main()
{
    long long n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    cout<<seq(n,k,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to add : Recursion is not my favorite method and maybe it is wrong

Comment: Do you actually want to list all the sequences for some reason? Or just determine how many there are?

Comment: Determine how many there are

Comment: so you want 6 as output?

Comment: The output has to be 6 because there are 6 sequences, not 3

Comment: I wonder what could be the problem

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the answer would simply be equal to `(n+k-1)!/(k!*(n-k)!)`, which is equal to binomial coefficient with repetitions allowed. But, you need to be wary of how quickly factorials can grow.

Comment: `(1,1 - 1,2 - 1,3 - 2,2 - 2,3 - 3,3)` here i see 7 item comma separated

Comment: 1,1 is just one of the sequences. The other ones are 1,2 -> 1,3 -> 2,2 -> 2,3 -> 3,3

Comment: Oops, I messed up the formula (due to trying to simplify it), in fact it is: `(n+k-1)!/(k!*(n-1)!)`, but that still, doesn't change the fact that it is the value of binomial coefficient with repetitions allowed.

Comment: That will output 4, not 6. And output 15 instead of 20 when n is 3 and k is 4

Comment: @Nson Let's take the example that you posted (n=3; k=2). That makes the formula, that I posted, to look like: `(3+2-1)!/(2!*(3-1)!)=4!/(2!*2!)=4*3*2*1/(2*1*2*1)=24/4=6`. How did you get `4`?

Comment: No, no. N is 2 and K is 3

Comment: @Nson Labels are irrelevant. I can relabel the parameters, but that wouldn't change the meaning of it (for your context, I can define k=N;n=K, and everything works). To be fair, I didn't even look at your notation, but, rather was going for the notation that is standard in combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it for a given n and k

```
long long seq(long long n, long long k,long long first,long long depth){
   if(depth > n){
       cnt = cnt + 1; // A leaf node is hit in the recursion tree
       return cnt;
   }
   else {
       for(long long i= first;i<=k;i++){    
            seq(n,k,i,depth+1); // Continue recursion
       }
   }
   return cnt;
}
int main()
{
    long long n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    cout<<seq(n,k,1,1);
    return 0;
}
```

Running code here : http://cpp.sh/4xr7a

Comment: _This kind of debugging can be made a lot easier by adding cout statements_ Well.. This kind of debugging can be made a lot easier by using a debugger.

Comment: What about N > 2 ?  You didn't use n anywhere in the modified function

Comment: When N = 3 and K = 3 , there are combinations such as 1 1 1 -> 1 1 2 -> 1 1 3 -> 1 2 2 , etc

Comment: Why using a recursion for just N = 2? That can be done with two loops.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag you @Some Guy

Comment: Thanks! One last question. Is that the most effective solution?

Comment: Bump. still need to know

Comment: No, this is still not the most efficient solution. This algorithm has some repeating subproblems and dynamic programming would give much better results in the case.

Comment: Oh so now I know why it takes 1.5 seconds instead of < 1.

Comment: All this for nothing. damn